# If $\{Z_{n}:n\geq 0\}$ is a time-homogeneous Markov process, $\{Y_{n}:= f(Z_{n}):n\geq0\}$ is also a time-homogeneous Markov process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $\{Z_{n}:n\geq 0\}$ be a time-homogeneous Markov process with state-space $S$ and
let $f: S\rightarrow S$ be a function. Then the stochastic process $\{Y_{n}:n\geq0\}$ defined by
$Y_{n}:= f(Z_{n})$, for $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}$, is a time-homogeneous Markov process.

If the statement above true or false?

I think the statement is true since we can express $Y_{n} = k$ as $Z_{n} = f^{-1}(k)$, so it is just another way of expressing Zn which is assumed to be a time-homogeneous Markov process. If what I have stated makes sense so far, my concern will be what if the function is not bijective, will it affect the result of $Y_n$ being time-homogenous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The statement is false.**

Let's consider an example. Let $\{Z_{n}:n\geq0\}$ be a Markov Chain with state spece $S=\{-1,0,1\}$ and tansition matrix
$$P=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}p_{-1,-1}&p_{-1,0}&p_{-1,1}\\p_{0,-1}&p_{0,0}&p_{0,1}\\p_{1,-1}&p_{1,0}&p_{1,1}\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{array}\right).$$
Let $\pi^{(0)}=\left[\pi_{-1},\pi_{0},\pi_{1}\right]:=\left[\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3}\right]$ be a initital distribution, and $f$ defined by $f(x):=|x|$. Therefore, we have $Y_{n}:=|Z_{n}|$.

Note that $\{Y_{n}:n\geq0\}$ is **not** Markov Chain. Indeed, on the one hand, we have that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(Y_{2}=0|Y_{0}=1,Y_{1}=1)&= \mathbb{P}(X_{2}=0\:\left|\:|X_{0}|=1,|X_{1}|=1\right.)\\
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(X_{2}=0,|X_{0}|=1,|X_{1}|=1)}{\mathbb{P}(|X_{0}|=1,|X_{1}|=1)}\\
&=\frac{p_{-1,0}\mathbb{P}(X_{1}=-1,|X_{0}|=1) + p_{1,0}\mathbb{P}(X_{1}=1,|X_{0}|=1)}{p_{-1,-1}\pi_{-1}+p_{1,-1}\pi_{1}+p_{-1,1}\pi_{-1}+p_{1,1}\pi_{1} }\\
&=\frac{p_{-1,0}(p_{-1,-1}\pi_{-1}+p_{-1,1}\pi_{1}) + p_{1,0}(p_{-1,1}\pi_{-1}+p_{1,1}\pi_{1})}{p_{-1,-1}\pi_{-1}+p_{1,-1}\pi_{1}+p_{-1,1}\pi_{-1}+p_{1,1}\pi_{1} }\\
&=\frac{\pi_{1}}{\pi_{1}}\\
&=1.
\end{align*}
But on the other hand, we have that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(Y_{2}=0|Y_{1}=1)&=\mathbb{P}(X_{2}=0\:|\:|X_{1}|=1)\\
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(X_{2}=0,|X_{1}|=1)}{\mathbb{P}(|X_{1}|=1)}\\
&=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X_{2}=0.X_{1}=-1)+\mathbb{P}(X_{2}=0.X_{1}=1)}{\mathbb{P}(X_{1}=-1)+\mathbb{P}(X_{1}=1)}\\&=\frac{p_{-1,0}\pi_{-1}+p_{1,0}\pi_{1}}{\pi_{-1}+\pi_{1}}\\
&=\frac{\pi_{-1}}{\pi_{-1}+\pi_{1}}\\
&=\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\\
&\neq 1
\end{align*}
Therefore, $\{Y_{n}:n\geq0\}$ does not satisfy the Markov property.

**Remark:** If $f$ is 1-1 then the statement is true. The proof is easy.